# Do unit strength bonuses on level-up actually work?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

When your unit levels up, you can either heal it for free or get a strength bonus (have not encountered any other perks yet). However, when I choose to get latter, it does not show anywhere - unit stats stay the same, there's no perk icon or anything.

Do those actually work?

Edit: nevermind, they do actually show up when you mouse over XP bar.
Also you seem to get XP when doing so, what's up with that?

Comment: Don't change the question you're asking, especially after it's been answered.  Ask another one instead.

Comment: But this is relevant information.

Comment: You're asking a completely different question now.  Before, it was about the level up perks.  Now, you're asking something about XP.  That's two different things.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they do.  They don't show in the actual strength, but when you select them, and mouse over an enemy, you can see the battle calculation taking that perk into account.  When applicable, that is.  Some of them aren't, depending on the unit and what you chose.

Comment: How do you answer questions so fast :O